# How to calculate the gradient with respect to "Input" layer in Caffe?

Tags: c++, gradient, caffe

I want to implement the algorithm proposed by paper "Generalizing to unseen domains via adversarial data augmentation" using Caffe framework. I have to compute the gradient with regard of input layer to add it onto the input blob. In PyTorch, it can be done by `grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, data)[0]`. But in Caffe, there is no function to do this as I know. So how to compute the gradient of "Input" layer in Caffe. The "Input" layer means input image in semantic segmentation.

I have tried call `net->input_blobs()[0]->cpu_diff()` after backpropagation, but values in `cpu_diff` are all 0. Obviously, Caffe does not compute the gradient of input layer in default. The overall algorithm is as the image shows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc62R.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what you want, try something like

```
for (int i=0; i<top_vec[0]->count(); i++) {
    top_vec[0]->mutable_cpu_diff()[i] = 1.0;
}

net->Backward(top_vec, propagate_down, bottom_vec);

for (int i=0; i<bottom_vec[0]->count(); i++) {
    std::cout << i << " : " << bottom_vec[0]->cpu_diff()[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I didn't see `net->Backward()` as you mentioned. Do you mean `caffe::Layer->Backward(top_vecs, propagate_down, bottom_vecs)`? However, even in this way I cannot still get the gradient with respect to the input layer. The membership variant `propagate_down` is set false in default and even when I create a new vector propagate_down, it still makes no effort.

Comment: Yes, `net->Backward()` may doesn't work, and `caffe::Layer->Backward()` works fine. Check this link for the sigmoidLayer's backward: https://github.com/suzyi/cpp/blob/master/caffe/8-layers/sigmoid_layer/main.cpp#L44

Comment: I understand what this code do. So, in a fully convolutional network, what I should do is first set all diff of top_vecs[0] to 1 by `caffe_set(top_vecs[0]->count(), 1.f, top_vecs[0]->mutable_cpu_data()`, then `net->ForwardBackward()`, finally `first_layer->Backward(top_vecs, propagate_down, bottom_vecs)`. The `first_layer` means the first convolutional layer after input layer. Is it right?

Comment: @PengJvNie Yes, the key point is setting diff of top blob to 1, before executing `.Backward()`.